Anime series with a tiny fairy drinking from a Saint Bernard dog's alcohol barrel
I watched this in the early 2000s, 2008 at the latest, on one of the main French TV channels. It was dubbed in French. From what I remember of the drawing style, this looked like a Japanese anime, and was most likely a series, which could also have been made in the 80s-90s. The target audience would have been young children (5-10 years old).
A young woman (teenager or early adult) is accompanied by a Saint Bernard dog wearing the cliché barrel on its collar, and a tiny (10-20 cm) flying fairy-type female character possibly named Gigi. They discuss what is inside the barrel, and either the woman or another character explains it is a liquid that provides heat for victims of the cold in the mountains, but does not explicitly mention it being alcohol.
I don't think the dog could talk.
Later on, the group are stranded in a snowy mountain, the fairy then decides to take a sip from the barrel, states something along the lines of "weeee, it really warms you up!", to which the woman replies "Gigi, have you been drinking?!". The fairy proceeds to talk silly nonsense, the kind of drunken behaviour you would expect in a kid's show.
I am not certain about the name "Gigi", and it might be that the fairy is only named that in French, and something else entirely in Japanese/English.
I tried, to no avail:

browsing lists of animation content with Saint Bernard dogs (Animaniacs, Looney Tunes and Bugs Bunny, as listed here, are not it);
searching for anime featuring fairies and a character named Gigi, which are not Magical Princess Minky Momo (which was titled Gigi in French). Although that series has a dog, its breed is not what I remember, and the magic character is too tall;
filtering out results related to Beethoven;
filtering results by site (anime dog st Bernard site:myanimelist.net/anime).


Do you remember any hair colors or something like that?

@jo1storm none. I also do not remember whether they had spiky hair, had to defeat a villain or other general, barely searchable for details

"Kidd Video" has a small fairy + a girl in the group of main characters, and Wikipedia cites a French dub, but although there seem to be some snow-themed episodes my (very quick) search found no dogs. Moreover, it's not Japanese, and I think people would remember it having a live-action intro sequence and musical intermissions.

Belle and Sebastian is an anime with a French dub where the dog has a barrel around her neck in some shots, but she's a Great Pyrenees, not a Saint Bernard, and I think it's grounded in reality (so no fairies).
